# PHP delete multiple images types in a folder

Tags: php

I'm sure this is quite simple but I've had no luck getting the correct syntax. What's a better way to write multiple extensions? Or is this way (below) as good as any?

```
<?php
    //Delete all image files in this folder
    $path = 'files/';

    if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if (filectime($file)< (time() - 2419200)) {
                if (preg_match('/\.png$/i', $file)) {
                    unlink($path.'/'.$file);
                }
                if (preg_match('/\.jpg$/i', $file)) {
                    unlink($path.'/'.$file);
                }
                if (preg_match('/\.tif$/i', $file)) {
                    unlink($path.'/'.$file);
                }
                if (preg_match('/\.gif$/i', $file)) {
                    unlink($path.'/'.$file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: you only need one preg_match `(.png|.jpg|.tif|.gif)`

Comment: I would use `substr` instead of a regex. It should be faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$extensions = array ('png', 'jpg', 'tif', 'gif'); // add any other extensions to this array

foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
    foreach (glob ($path . '/*.' . $extension) as $file) {
        if (filectime ($file) < (time () - 2419200)) {
            unlink ($file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your missing the time check and you dont need 2 loops

Comment: 1 loop: .. `glob("*.{png,jpg,tif,gif}", GLOB_BRACE)` ..